# Exception while starting oim_server1 in Oracle Identity Manager

Tags: weblogic12c

In my project, I am using Oracle Identity and Access Management-12.2.1.3.0. I did installation of weblogic (fmw_12.2.1.3.0_infrastructure.jar), Oracle SOA Suite 12c (fmw_12.2.1.3.0_soa_quickstart.jar), Oracle Identity Governance (OIM 12c) 12.2.1.3.0 (fmw_12.2.1.3.0_idm.jar). Executed RCU for schema creation and did weblogic domain configuration also.

**In weblogic domain configuration, I gave username - "weblogic" and passoword - "Welcome1" for keystore, OIMSchemaPassword, sysadmin and WeblogicAdminKey in at credentials step.**

Node manager, weblogic server and soa_server1 are starting smoothly but when I am starting oim_server1, I am getting exception -

```
<Dec 15, 2017 6:13:41,431 PM IST> <Info> <oracle.iam.OIMPostConfigManager> <BEA-000000> < task failed :ENCRYPT_CONFIGURATION>

<Dec 15, 2017 6:13:41,433 PM IST> <Error> <oracle.iam.OIMPostConfigManager> <BEA-000000> <Task failed.::ENCRYPT_CONFIGURATION>

<Dec 15, 2017 6:13:41,433 PM IST> <Error> <oracle.iam.OIMPostConfigManager> <BEA-000000> <Task failed.::ENCRYPT_CONFIGURATION>

<Dec 15, 2017 6:13:42,000 PM IST> <Info> <oracle.iam.OIMPostConfigManager> <BEA-000000> <updating feature:ENCRYPT_CONFIGURATIONwith state :FAILEDwith executionTimeNot Applicable>

<Dec 15, 2017 6:13:42,046 PM IST> <Error> <oracle.iam.OIMPostConfigManager> <BEA-000000> <Shutting down the BootStrap Process. Please fix the problem and start the OIM Managed server again to complete OIM BootStrap. OR, If you want to skip the feature which has failed, mark the feature as complete using sql 'update oimbootstate set state='COMPLETE' where featurename='FAILED_FEATURE_NAME' and start the Managed Server again. In the latter case, you will have to manually perform the task being done by the failed feature. Refer to the Install documentations for the same>

<Dec 15, 2017 6:13:42,046 PM IST> <Error> <oracle.iam.OIMPostConfigManager> <BEA-000000> <Shutting down the BootStrap Process. Please fix the problem and start the OIM Managed server again to complete OIM BootStrap. OR, If you want to skip the feature which has failed, mark the feature as complete using sql 'update oimbootstate set state='COMPLETE' where featurename='FAILED_FEATURE_NAME' and start the Managed Server again. In the latter case, you will have to manually perform the task being done by the failed feature. Refer to the Install documentations for the same>

java.lang.Exception: Exception occured while encrypting the configuration

        at oracle.iam.OIMPostConfigManager.config.util.EncryptConfigurationAndDB.encryptConfiguration(EncryptConfigurationAndDB.java:181)

        at oracle.iam.OIMPostConfigManager.config.OIMConfigManager.encryptConfiguration(OIMConfigManager.java:5319)

        at oracle.iam.OIMPostConfigManager.config.OIMConfigManager.executeAndRegisterTask(OIMConfigManager.java:1634)

        at oracle.iam.OIMPostConfigManager.config.OIMConfigManager.configureOIM(OIMConfigManager.java:1556)

        at oracle.iam.OIMPostConfigManager.config.OIMConfigManager.doExecute(OIMConfigManager.java:1175)

        at oracle.iam.OIMPostConfigManager.appListener.BootStrapListener.preStart(BootStrapListener.java:128)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.BaseLifecycleFlow$LifecycleListenerAction.run(BaseLifecycleFlow.java:240)

        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)

        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)

        at weblogic.application.internal.ApplicationContextImpl$WLSSecurityProvider.invokePrivilegedAction(ApplicationContextImpl.java:1594)

        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.BaseLifecycleFlow$LifecycleListenerAction.invoke(BaseLifecycleFlow.java:201)

        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.HeadLifecycleFlow.prepare(HeadLifecycleFlow.java:245)

        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)

        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)

        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:241)

        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:66)

        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)

        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)

        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:166)

        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:41)

        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:193)

        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:31)

        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments$2.doItem(ConfiguredDeployments.java:741)

        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.parallel.BucketInvoker.invoke(BucketInvoker.java:138)

        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:749)

        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:363)

        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:232)

        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:219)

        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:133)

        at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)

        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1287)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:333)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:375)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:786)

        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)

        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)

        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)

        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)

        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)

        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)

        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)

        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Exception occurred during generation of keystores.

        at oracle.iam.OIMPostConfigManager.config.util.EncryptConfigurationAndDB.encryptConfiguration(EncryptConfigurationAndDB.java:161)

        ... 66 more`enter code here`
```

I am starting soa_server1 and oim_server1 using command startManagedWebLogic.cmd soa_server1 and startManagedWebLogic.cmd oim_server1 respectively.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem. Please add it here if you did.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer to this problem:

Try to check if you have password to `/app/oracle/product/ofm/user_projects/domains/IAM_domain/config/fmwconfig/default-keystore.jks` by running following command

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -list -keystore /app/oracle/product/ofm/user_projects/domains/IAM_domain/config/fmwconfig/default-keystore.jks -storepass PASSWORD_OF_THE_DEFAULT_KEYSTORE
```

If the KeyStore entries are displayed, at least this much can be sure that the KeyStore is not corrupt or tampered with. As your password is correct, it may be possible that in the Credential store, somehow password may be incorrect.

So, log in the Enterprise Manager console (http://hostname:7001/em), Weblogic Domain --> IAM_Domain --> Right Click --> Security --> Credentials --> oim.

Then edit the password of default-keystore.jks in EM And then restart the servers.

With the incorrect password, you will receive:

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException:` Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

As you do not know the password to default-keystore.jks; take backup of this file, delete it and create new at the same location with same name and alias as orakey

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -alias orakey -keypass <NEWPASS> -keystore default-keystore.jks -storepass <NEWPASS> -validity 3600
```